# initializer_list ctor is not being called in clang++

Tags: c++, constructor, g++, clang++, initializer-list

I have such code

```
struct Foo {
    Foo() {}

    Foo(std::initializer_list<Foo>) {
        std::cout << "initializer list" << std::endl;
    }

    Foo(const Foo&) {
        std::cout << "copy ctor" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo a;
    Foo b(a);
    Foo c{a};
}
```

Compiling it with `g++ -std=c++20 -o main main.cpp` and running gives me such output:

```
copy ctor
copy ctor
initializer list
```

**But** running binary compiled with `clang++ -std=c++20 -o main main.cpp` outputs the following:

```
copy ctor
copy ctor
```

So why are those two outputs are different?

Comment: While the initializer list will gladly overtake other (potentially) matching parameterized constructors, I'm not sure why you expect this code to *not* call the copy constructor.

Comment: clang compiler has determined that initilizer-list was not required in this situtation (you only passed a single value), so copy was sufficient,  change to `Foo c{a,a};` and you'll see that initializer-list will now get called on both compilers

Comment: This is [CWG2137](https://wg21.link/CWG2137) (clang does not seem to have implemented this yet, gcc is right)